# how to pass current filter result to an anchor so i can generate a pdf base on that search input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

**Asp.net core mvc 3.1**
i have a index view that shows a list of movies, where i added a search text box, and i would like to know if there is any way to pass that search value to the anchor element. This anchor element points to an action that generates a pdf view. But i would like to pass that search input to an anchor so i can query based on that input, and generate diferent pdf results base on that searched input...
I would really appreciated if you guys could help me...

**MoviesController**

```
    // GET: Movies
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search)
    {
      
            var movies = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).OrderBy(m=>m.Name);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            var query = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre);
              var searchedItems = query.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(search) || m.Genre.Name.Contains(search) || m.Year.ToString().Contains(search));
            return View(await searchedItems.ToListAsync());
           
        }
        
            return View( await movies.ToListAsync());
        
    }

    public IActionResult GeneratePdf(string linkedSearch)
    {
        var movies = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
        return new ViewAsPdf("GeneratePdf", movies)
        {
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
            PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4
        };
       
    }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieListApp.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Add new movie</a>
</p>
<a asp-action="Index">Refresh</a>
@* Table Omitted for brevity *@
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Movies" method="get">
    <p>
        Search:<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="name, Genre, year" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" />
    </p>
</form>

<a asp-action="GeneratePdf" asp-controller="Movies">Generate Pdf</a>
```

[Searched Results..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJaS.png)

**Solution**
it is worth mentioning that pdf views are generate with rotativa version 1.2 , the GeneratePdf action method links to a view... MoviesContrller

```
// GET: Movies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search)
        {
            ViewData["Search"] = search;
                var movies = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).OrderBy(m=>m.Name);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                var query = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre);
                  var searchedItems = query.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(search) || m.Genre.Name.Contains(search) || m.Year.ToString().Contains(search));
                return View(await searchedItems.ToListAsync());
               
            }
            
                return View( await movies.ToListAsync());
            
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePdf(string linkedSearch)
        {
            
            var movies = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).OrderBy(m => m.Name);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedSearch))
            {
                var query = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre);
                var searchedItems = query.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(linkedSearch) || m.Genre.Name.Contains(linkedSearch) || m.Year.ToString().Contains(linkedSearch));

                return new ViewAsPdf("GeneratePdf",await searchedItems.ToListAsync())
                {
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
                    PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4
                };
            }

            return new ViewAsPdf("GeneratePdf", await movies.ToListAsync())
            {
                PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
                PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4
            };
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieListApp.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Add new movie</a>
</p>
<a asp-action="Index">Refresh</a>
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Movies" method="get">
    <p>
        Search:<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="name, Genre, year" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" />
    </p>
</form>
@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Genre</label>>
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.MovieId">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.MovieId">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.MovieId">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

}
<a asp-action="GeneratePdf" asp-controller="Movies" asp-route-linkedSearch="@ViewData["Search"]">Generate Pdf</a>
```

**Diferent pdf based on search**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj75M.png

**Another pdf base on another search**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75MDV.png

Comment: Do you mean when you would input some `search value` on your search textbox based on the value it would create `Generate Pdf` each time right?

Comment: yes, that would be nice, idk if its even posible... or  if i could just saved the search string in a global variable in the index action method . and then use it in the generate pdf action method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor tag helper supports passing query parameters using the `asp-route-{value}` attribute. But first you need to pass the search value to the view. For that you can use the `ViewData` dictionary.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search)
{ 
    // pass the search string to the view so that the anchor can pass it to the GeneratePdf action
    ViewData["Search"] = search;
    
    // rest of the code
}
```

Then inside the view:

```
<a asp-action="GeneratePdf" asp-controller="Movies" asp-route-linkedSearch="@ViewData["Search"]">Generate Pdf</a>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value

Comment: Thank you so much... You are the Boss that fixed my issue... I am going to paste the code to see if it helps somebody else...  Damn i wish i was as good as Dimitris..